# Creating special UIButtons text from substring in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, nsdictionary

I am trying to create a special button text based off of a string that I am building from information from a user. I think I am doing this right, but the IDE is telling me that

> / 'NSDictionary' is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

But I am doing that here

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: substring1 as String,
    attributes: NSDictionary(
        object: font!,
    forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

What am I doing wrong here? Here is the whole code for this:

```
//applying the line break mode
customerInfoButton?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
var buttonText: NSString = "Fight club \n" +
                           points + " pt. \n" +
                           "rank:" + myRank

//getting the range to separate the button title strings
var newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.rangeOfString("\n")

//getting both substrings
var substring1: NSString = ""
var substring2: NSString = ""
var substring3: NSString = ""

if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    substring1 = buttonText.substringToIndex(newlineRange.location)
    substring2 = buttonText.substringFromIndex(newlineRange.location)
    substring3 = buttonText.substringFromIndex(newlineRange.location)
}

//assigning diffrent fonts to both substrings
let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12.0)
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: substring1 as String,
    attributes: NSDictionary(
        object: font!,
    forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])

let attrString3 = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: substring3 as String,
    attributes: NSDictionary(
        object: font!,
        forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])

let pointFont:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.0)
let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: substring2 as String,
    attributes: NSDictionary(
        object: pointFont!,
        forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])

//appending both attributed strings
attrString.appendAttributedString(attrString1)

//assigning the resultant attributed strings to the button
customerInfoButton?.setAttributedTitle(attrString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your attributed string in this way:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font!] 
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1 as String, attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: That works and it is a hell of a lot cleaner and easier to read then what I was doing. Thank you very much I really appreciate it!